# How to delete a Kubernetes resource entirely with jq

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I'm trying to use `jq` (and yq) to delete a single Kubernetes resource.
I thought I could do with this with `del` but it is leaving behind a `null`.

```
$ cat test.yaml | yq -y '. | del(select(.kind == "Namespace" and .metadata.name == "bar"))' 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
spec: {}
status: {}
--- null
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: baz
spec: {}
status: {}
```

My test data:

```
$ cat test.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: bar
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: baz
spec: {}
status: {}
```

How do I get this output?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: baz
spec: {}
status: {}
```

Comment: There are two incompatible tools called yq. It looks like you're using this one: https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming from the syntax that you are using [kislyuk yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq).

`del` is not the right tool for this job. `del` takes in a stream of N values and returns a stream of N modified values. In your case it takes in a stream of three values and returns a stream of three values. You observe that it leaves the first and last objects unchanged, but replaces the second with `null`. For each value it inputs, it evaluates its argument filter to decide how to change that value - every location emitted by that filter will be removed. You have provided as its argument a `select` filter. A select filter takes in a stream of values, and emits a stream of *some* of those values unmodified, while discarding others, depending on its filter argument. (Actually, it's a little more complicated than that - if you pass it a filter that returns multiple values, it can actually emit more values than it received, but that's not relevant here.)

In this case, your `select` filter returns nothing for the first object, because it doesn't match, so the `del` changes nothing. For the second object, the `select` filter *does* match the object, so the `del` filter is equivalent to `del(.)`. The docs aren't terribly clear about what to expect when the filter you pass to `del` doesn't pick a key (or index) in the object (or array), but instead the whole thing, but clearly the behaviour in practice is that it replaces it with `null`.

If you followed along with that explanation, you may see where this is going. `select` is already the tool you want! There is no need for `del` here at all. `select` is the mechanism to keep only *some* of a stream of objects. Try:

```
$ cat ~/scratch/test.yaml | yq -y 'select(.kind != "Namespace" or .metadata.name != "bar")'
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
spec: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: baz
spec: {}
status: {}
```

Comment: TWIMC: This solution also works with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), just drop the `-y` option, and (if using a version prior to 4.18) add the `e` or `eval` command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), the Go implementation of jq:

```
gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output 'select(.metadata.name != "bar")' test.yaml
```